# How to add Zend REST API to an existing Concrete5 site?

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, concrete5

I was tasked with developing a REST API using zend framework 2 for a web site created with concrete5 cms. I am very new php and have no idea where to start.

Specifically, my question is about installation and routing. How can I install zend framework on my existing concrete5 project. After that, what should I do to route REST requests to Zend controllers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Apigility. This is a Zend solution for the use case you suggest (publishing existing code as an API).

https://apigility.org